# The difference between 'lots of' and 'a lot of'

Tags: word-difference, determiners

> I have **a lot** of pens
>
> I have **lots** of pens

What is the difference? I do not see any difference but as per my teacher there is a difference which till date I am unable to understand

Comment: There is no semantic difference, but there is a grammatical difference: singular "lot", but **not** plural "lots",  takes "a" as determiner and allows a limited amount of premodification (_I have a whole lot of pens_).

Answer (score 1):

If they want to get really detailed, **a lot** means a specific amount--lot being the amount.

Say pen boxes come in sets, or lots, of 10. If you have a lot, you have 10.

To me, I have lots of pens means you have some amount of pens that is great in amount.

I think, however, people use these statements equally. And, in my opinion, I like the second one more because it uses less words, making it quicker to read.